# Java/Android : shortest way (lambda?) to pass a target handler to a custom button referencing this as a weak reference

Tags: java, android, lambda, weak-references, generic-type-argument

I created my custom buttons in Android. Before, I just had a very simple interface to pass target method as a callback for my buttons :

```
public interface onTouchInterface {
    void onTouch(); 
}
```

When I wanted to pass a callback to a button, I just used lambda expression :

```
mybutton.addTarget(this::mycallback);
```

which is a shortcut for

```
mybutton.addTarget(new onTouchInterface() { 
    @Override 
    void onTouch() { this.mycallback() }
});
```

The problem is that I realized that `this` (which is often a Fragment in my case) was still in the memory even after I removed my fragment from anywhere, while garbage collector should have removed it. I discovered it was "encapsuled" by my lambda expression.

My question is : how can I make the shortest syntax while having a weak reference for this ? For the moment, I created this class instead of my old very simple interface :

```
public abstract static class Target<T>
{
    protected WeakReference<T> scope ;

    static protected class ScopeNotPresentException extends Exception {}

    protected Target(T scope) { this.scope = new WeakReference<T>(scope); }

    // this is the raw callback called by the button when user clicks
    // it throws an exception if the scope is null, otherwise it executes onTouch (to be overrided)
    final public void onTouchRawCallback() throws ScopeNotPresentException {
        if(scope.get() == null)
            throw new ScopeNotPresentException();
        else
            onTouch(scope.get());
    }

    // when this subclassed method is executed, the scope is verified to be not null
    protected void onTouch(T scope) { }

}
```

My button class raw callback does :

```
try {
    mTarget.onTouchRawCallback();
}
catch(Target.ScopeNotPresentException e){
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "target button method was ignored because scope weak ref is null");
}
```

So, if scope.get() is null, the exception is triggered and `onTouch()` is not called. Finally, all my Fragment add a handler to their buttons like so :

```
mybutton.addTarget(new MyCustomButton.Target<MyFragment>(this) {
    @Override
    protected void onTouch(MyFragment scope) {
        scope.fragmentCustomClickHandler(); 
    }
});
```

But this is of course much more verbose than `mybutton.addTarget(this::mycallback);`. I saw that I couldn't use lambda for generic typed class with arguments passed to constructor.

Do you have any idea of a better implementation so I could keep using lambda short syntax while having a safe retrieval of `this`, using weak references ? (For exemple, in swift, it's
`addTarget({ [weak self] self?.myCallback(); })` which stops if self is null)

Comment: When the listener keeps the `this` alive, it implies that the button is keeping the listener alive, which implies that the button is still alive. You don’t want a button allowing the target fragment to get garbage collected and producing an exception on every touch. When you think, the button should not be alive, you should fix the button’s lifecycle. When the button should be alive, but not update this particular fragment, you should remove the listener instead of making it throw an exception on every event.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean if I remove the fragment, the callback (strongly held by the button AND the fragment) should be Garbage collected because fragment ref is deleted, then button ref is deleted, and then no object hold the callback anymore